# rails get array of associated unique objects from array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`Trip` and `Alert` model are associate like: Trip `has_many` alerts

I have an object like `@alerts = Alert.all`

Now I want to find `Array` of unique `Trip` from `@alerts`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
 Trip.where(id: @alerts.map(&:trip_id).uniq)
```

This:

```
  @alerts.map(&:trip_id).uniq
```

Gives you an array of unique trip ids based on your alerts.

BTW, this gives you an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pluck` method on `@alerts`, paired with `uniq`:

```
@alerts.pluck(:trip_id).uniq
```

- [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) will return an array of all `Trip` ids.
- [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) will remove all duplicated values (i.e. ids) from the array.

The result will be an `Array` of unique `Trip` ids.